# GigE Vision cameras bring ports of an ethernet switch to crash

Tags: networking, switch, camera

we have observed a curious behavior with GigE Vision cameras connected to a NETGEAR PS108 switch. Three cameras, 2x Allied Vision Manta G-145B NIR and a Basler Scout are wired to the switch and also two 100MBit devices:

**Switch 1**

- Port 1: cam 1
- Port 2: cam 2
- Port 3: cam 3
- Port 4: IP controlled power outlet (100MBit)
- Port 5: NI Ethernet to Serial (100Mbit)
- Port 8: PC 1Gbit Intel network card)

This configuration was working for years but we had a fluctuation of voltage a few days ago. Since then the all three camera ports are freezing if image acquisition is in progress, even if only one camera is active. The not camera ports continue to work. After cold restart of the switch the camera ports works for a while and freeze again. We have tested the setup with a new identical switch, but the behavior was the same.

My guess is that it is related to GigE Vision protocol, because the problem relates to the camera ports only, but my knowledge of this standard is not deep enough. Has someone an idea what can be the cause for the crashes of the ports?

We looked for a quick problem solution and have connected all the cameras to the new switch and hung the switch to a remote controlled power socket in order to restart in error case. Now the setup is:

**Switch 2**

- Port 1: cam 1
- Port 2: cam 2
- Port 3: cam 3
- ....
- Port 8:  to switch 1

**Switch 1**

- Port 1: Switch 2
- Port 4: IP controlled power outlet
- Port 5: NI Ethernet to Serial (100Mbit)
- Port 8 to PC (1Gbit network card)

Now the problem does not occur anymore.